# Как передавать javascript выражение в ui-grid="" (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Есть такой массив:

```
$scope.ChemicalGroups
[
    ...
    HashName: "G815D9D3776614A985A4B18E437349DE2"
    ...
]
```

Есть такой код:

```
$scope.ChemicalGroups.forEach(function (chemicalGroup) {
        var valStrl = chemicalGroup.HashName;
            chemicalGroup[valStrl] = {
                enableColumnMenus: false,
                enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
                enableVerticalScrollbar: 2,
                data: []
            };
});
```

Т.е у меня может быть сколько угодно элементов в массиве ChemicalGroups и для каждого нужно создать ui-grid. Поле HashName я хочу использовать как уникальное имя grid-а (gridOptions).

Код html:

```
<div id="{{item.Id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div ui-grid="item[HashName]" class="grid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В этом случае генерируется исключение, пишет: **Token '[' is not a valid**

Так тоже не получается - `ui-grid={{item[HashName]}}`

---

Пытался делать так:

```
$scope.ChemicalGroups.forEach(function (chemicalGroup) {
                var valStrl = chemicalGroup.HashName;
                var model = $parse(valStrl);
                model.assign($scope, {
                    enableColumnMenus: false,
                    enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
                    enableVerticalScrollbar: 2,
                    data: []
                });
            });
```

Html:

```
<div id="{{item.Id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div ui-grid="item.HashName" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В этом случае в стандартном скрипте **ui-grid.js** происходит исключение т.к туда передается строка HashName. Хотя в $scope я добавил перед этим объект, который называется так же как строка HashName - `model.assign($scope...` (я проверял в $scope он есть).
Но это выражение: **ui-grid="item.HashName"** получает почему-то не объект а строку.

Как сделать чтобы он распознал именно объект с таким именем?
Возможно ли в `ui-grid=""` передавать какое-либо javascript выражение, например такое: `{{item[HashName]}}`, насколько я понял так делать нельзя.
Любые предложения.

Comment: ничего непонятно что ты хочешь сделать и что делал. `ui-grid="item.[HashName]"` - здесь и в обычном яваскрипте будет ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: Точка лишняя уже убрал

Comment: Я хочу для каждого элемента массива ChemicalGroups генерировать grid

Comment: После убирания точки, должна пропасть и ошибка _Token '[' is not a valid_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как имя поля у тебя хранится в поле `HashName` у объекта. То и получать объект нужно именно по значению находящемуся в этом поле:

```
<div ui-grid="item[item.HashName]" class="grid">
```

Comment: Так не работает, даже не доходит до этого места `var grid = new Grid(options);` в ui-grid.js. Ошибок в консоли нет.

Comment: @endovitskiiy, почему ты думаешь что не доходит? Эта запись делает именно то, что ты хотел: передает значение поля с ключом равным значению поля _item.HashName_ - собственно объект которых ты создавал. Если ошибок нет, значит проблема где-то еще. Попробуй сделать [mcve] чтобы можно было его запустить и посмотреть, что действительно не работает

Comment: не доходит потому что у меня в том месте стоит breakpoint. И он до туда просто не доходит.

Comment: @endovitskiiy, а до куда он доходит?

Comment: В ui-grid.js есть метод, называется createGrid. В этом случае он не вызывается. А эта строка `var grid = new Grid(options);`  в этом методе.

Comment: вообще обращение к item в html должно быть таким вроде `{{item[item.HashName]}}`, но так тоже не работает.

Comment: @endovitskiiy, без рабочего примера твоего кода, в котором воспроизводится описанное поведение можно долго гадать что и где происходит. Поэтому просто добавь [mcve] например на сервисе: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50604/discussion-between-grundy-and-endovitskiiy).